# I need to create table in Postgresql by python in VScode

Tags: python, database, postgresql, create-table

main.py

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, HTTPException, Depends
from fastapi.params import Body
from pydantic import BaseModel
from random import randrange
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import time
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from . import models
from .database import engine, SessionLocal

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

class Post(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool = True
@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello world"}

@app.get("/sqlalchemy")
def test_posts(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return {"status": "success"}
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:20050930@localhost/fastapi'

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from .database import Base
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, default=True)
```

I was expecting to create table but there are some errors

Comment: Could you provide the error?

Comment: We are supposed to guess at what the errors where?

Comment: Oh we're ? okay then :')